# NAudio: Using MixingSampleProvider correctly with VolumeSampleProvider

Tags: c#, naudio

I have been using NAudio with the 
"Fire and Forget Audio Playback with NAudio" tutorial (thank you Mark for this awesome utility!) as written here:
http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.nl/2014/02/fire-and-forget-audio-playback-with.html

I managed to add a VolumeSampleProvider to it, using the MixingSampleProvider as input. However, when I now play two sounds right after each other, the first sound always gets the volume of the second as well, even though the first is already playing.

So my question is: How do I add sounds with an individual volume per sound?

This is what I used:

```
        mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(waveformat);
        mixer.ReadFully = true;
        volumeProvider = new VolumeSampleProvider(mixer);
        panProvider = new PanningSampleProvider(volumeProvider);
        outputDevice.Init(panProvider);
        outputDevice.Play();
```

Answer (score 4):

I realized (thanks to itsmatt) that the only way to make this work, is to leave the mixer alone and adjust the panning and volume of each CachedSound individually, before adding it to the mixer. Therefore I needed to rewrite the CachedSoundSampleProvider, using a pan and volume as extra input parameters.

This is the new constructor:

```
    public CachedSoundSampleProvider(CachedSound cachedSound, float volume = 1, float pan = 0)
    {
        this.cachedSound = cachedSound;
        LeftVolume = volume * (0.5f - pan / 2);
        RightVolume = volume * (0.5f + pan / 2);
    }
```

And this is the new Read() function:

```
    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        long availableSamples = cachedSound.AudioData.Length - position;
        long samplesToCopy = Math.Min(availableSamples, count);

        int destOffset = offset;
        for (int sourceSample = 0; sourceSample < samplesToCopy; sourceSample += 2)
        {
            float outL = cachedSound.AudioData[position + sourceSample + 0];
            float outR = cachedSound.AudioData[position + sourceSample + 1];

            buffer[destOffset + 0] = outL * LeftVolume;
            buffer[destOffset + 1] = outR * RightVolume;
            destOffset += 2;
        }

        position += samplesToCopy;
        return (int)samplesToCopy;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% certain of what you are asking and I don't know if you solved this already but here's my take on this.

`ISampleProvider` objects play the "pass the buck" game to their source `ISampleProvider` via the `Read()` method.  Eventually, someone does some actual reading of audio bytes.  Individual `ISampleProvider` classes do whatever they do to the bytes.

`MixingSampleProvider`, for instance, takes N audio sources... those get mixed.  When `Read()` is called, it iterates the audio sources and reads `count` bytes from each.

Passing it to a `VolumeSampleProvider` handles all the bytes (from those various sources) as a group... it says:

```
buffer[offset+n] *= volume;
```

That's going to adjust the bytes across the board... so every byte gets adjusted in the buffer by the `volume` multiplier;

The `PanningSampleProvider` just provides a multiplier to the stereo audio and adjusts the bytes accordingly, doing the same sort of thing as the `VolumeSampleProvider`.

If you want to individually handle audio source volumes, you need to handle that upstream of the `MixingSampleProvider`.  Essentially, the things that you pass to the MixingSampleProvider need to be able to have their volume adjusted independently.

If you passed a bunch of `SampleChannel` objects to your `MixingSampleProvider`... you could accomplish independent volume adjustment. The `Samplechannel` class incorporates a `VolumeSampleProvider` object and provides a `Volume` property that allows one to set the volume on that `VolumeSampleProvider` object.

`SampleChannel` also incorporates a `MeteringSampleProvider` that provides reporting of the maximum sample value during a given period.  It raises an event that gives you an array of those values, one per channel.

Comment: Dear Matt, thank you for this answer. I will have to take a closer look at the SampleChannel class to find out if I can make it work. It has been over a year since I last worked on this code, so I don't imagine I'll know very soon. Greetings.